# react-navigation drawer how to set props and style to route components?

Tags: react-native, routes, react-navigation

I'm using a drawer for navigation and can't figure out how to set styles / props for the components used in the routes.

Drawer is created like this:

```
const navigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home,
    OtherPage,
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(navigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={displayDisclaimer:true};
    this.pressDisclaimer = this.pressDisclaimer.bind(this);
  }

  pressDisclaimer(){
    disclaimerPassed = true;
    this.setState({displayDisclaimer:false});
  }

  render(){
    // return <Drawer/>
    if(this.state.displayDisclaimer)
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Disclaimer clickHandler={this.pressDisclaimer}/>
        </View>
      )
    else return <AppContainer/>;
  }  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

So if I want to add a style for some pages I would normally render the component like `<MyComponent style = {this.style.moreStyle} otherProps={propsHere}/>`

How can I set this up since the createDrawerNavigator does not take the component implementation as the parameters?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but this is what I do in my main file:

```
import Home from './components/home'
import OtherPage from './components/otherpage'
import DrawerScreen from './components/drawerscreen'
import LoginScreen from './components/loginscreen'

const navigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {screen: Home},
    OtherPage: {screen: OtherPage},
    LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
  },
  {
    contentComponent:   ({ navigation }) => (
          <DrawerScreen navigation={navigation} />
        ),
    drawerWidth: 300,
      initialRouteName: "LoginScreen"
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);

 export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
   return (

       <AppContainer />

    );
  }
}
```

And then in my file for my drawer component I do something like:

```
import { DrawerActions, NavigationEvents, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

export default class DrawerScreen extends Component {

  navigateToScreen = (route) => () => {
 const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
   routeName: route
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer())
}


 render () {

  const { navigation } = this.props;
  const homeProps = navigation.getChildNavigation('Home');

    console.log(homeProps);
console.log(navigation);
return (
<View>
  <ScrollView>
    <View>


                <View>
                <View>
                <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')} title="Home"/>
                </View>
                </View>
                <View>
                <View style={styles.myMargins}>
                <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('OtherPage', {propsFromDrawer: "blahblahblah", styleprops: "blahblahblah"})} title="Other Page"/>
                </View>
                </View>


    </View>

  </ScrollView>
</View>
 );
}

}
```

Here the drawer would be getting props from Home and would be sending other props to Other Page when clicking the button for Other Page. I'm not sure if this will work with the structure of what you're doing but it's what works in my app.

Edit: Here is an example of ways to navigate from OtherPage.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
View,
Text,
 ScrollView,
 StyleSheet,
 ActivityIndicator,
 TouchableOpacity,
 BackHandler,
 } from 'react-native';

import { NavigationEvents, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';
export default class OtherPage extends Component {

static navigationOptions = {
title: 'OtherPage',
headerStyle: {
  backgroundColor: '#0000CD',
},
headerTintColor: '#fff',
};



constructor(props){
 super(props)

 this.state = {stuffInState: 'blahblahblah'}

}


componentDidMount() {

this.backHandler = 
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  return true;
  });

   }

  componentWillUnmount() {
  this.backHandler.remove();
  }

  render(){

  const { navigation } = this.props;
  const propsFromDrawer = navigation.getParam('propsFromDrawer') || '';
  const styleProps = navigation.getParam('styleprops') || '';

  //console.log(this.state);
  //console.log(navigation);

return(<View>
  <NavigationEvents
onWillFocus={payload => {this.setState({stuff: stuffFromProps})}}
/>
 <Header
leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#fff', onPress: () => 
 this.props.navigation.openDrawer() }}
 centerComponent={{ text: this.state.title, style: { color: '#fff' } }}
rightComponent={{ icon: 'home', color: '#fff', onPress: () => 
 this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}}

 />

<View>
<TouchableOpacity

onPress={() =>

this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {
 propsImSending: 'blahblahblah',

})} title="Home"
>
<Text>Home</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

</View>);
}


}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try it out and adapt to my app. Question, will it work the same if I call a navigate from within the OtherPage?i.e link in the page and using the drawer links as shortcuts.

Comment: There are a few different ways you can navigate from within OtherPage. I'll edit my answer to include an example.